# Multiple timers or single task with multiple counter?

Tags: arduino, embedded, stm32

Assume you have some functions that must be called at different point in times but continuosly (constant task like each 250ms, each 2s, each 5 mins).
Is it better to use 4-5 timers each one dedicated to a task or is it better to code everything in the smaller task and then use a counter variable to run the other function?

e.g.

```
//callback each 250ms
void 250ms_TASK(){
    if (counter % 8 != 0){ //250ms*8 = 2s
        return;
    }

    // do 2 sec stuff

    if (counter != 4800){ //250ms*4800 = 20min
        return;
    }
    //do 20min stuff
    counter = 0;
}
```

Assume also that you want to avoid/be bulletproof to situations like this:

- before doing 2 secs stuff you MUST be sure that the 8th 250ms task is computed.
- before doing 20 min stuff you MUST be sure that the 4800th 250ms and the 600th 2s task is computed.

The question is related to best practice and performance.

Moreover is it better to perform those calculations in the callback or use the callback to modify flags and perform the calculations in the main loop ?

Comment: You have tagged with two very different platforms - arduino and stm32.  The answer may not be the same for each.  Equally the answer might differ depending on whether you already has an RTOS scheduler for example. Any solution has to meet *your* application's timing constraints, so the solution may also differ depending on those. If execution order of coincident time-triggered tasks matters, execute them in that order.  In an RTOS it would be sufficient to give each task an appropriate priority.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using STM32 since you tagged STM32.

Unless your application is very much time critical that you need to use preemptive and asynchronous timer interrupts (for example 5 mins task is very important so it should be called ***even while*** a separated 250ms callback task is running), using multiple timer interrupts is just waste of timers and you need to use as fewer interrupts as possible IMHO. Counting variable is not costly so it is okay to do that.

The real consideration is the length of tasks. The ISRs should be as short as possible so if the timer callback tasks are quite long you should use flags and use polling operation in the main loop. Polling flags is more preferable especially when you are using multiple callbacks in a single timer ISR. Imagine the moment that 250ms, 2s, and 20min callbacks should be called in the ISR and the ISR will take 3 times longer than usual.

By the way, if you decide to use a single timer, why not using [SysTick](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0179b/ar01s02s08.html)? The SysTick timer is provided in every Cortex M MCUs and its operation is the same across the MCU families. You can easily configure this as 1ms interrupt timer very easily. As far as you use polling in the main loop 1ms interrupt must be fine. There are many tutorials on Systick (for example, [part1](http://www.zembedded.com/cortex-m3-sys-tick-explained-part-i/) and [part2](http://www.zembedded.com/cortex-m3-systick-explained-part-ii/))

Comment: It is also tagged Arduino, so who knows what platform the question relates to?

Comment: @Clifford, I don't know. So I stated at the beginning. And also my answer is actually in general and it can also apply to Arduino. The platform-dependent content in my answer is about Systick, which is for STM32 and ARM-based Arduino board (e.g. Arduino Zero). And also AVR Arduino does not have preemptive interrupt services.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this for tasks that aren't very time critical, is to implement a single timer, which triggers once every millisecond.

That timer then goes through a list of registered "software timers" and checks if it is time for them to be executed. If so, the timer then calls a function pointer which contains the timer-specific code. That is, a callback function called upon by the timer driver.

If these functions are kept minimal, for example just setting a flag, you can execute them from the main timer ISR.

Answer (score 1):

You can make various arguments regarding power consumption and real timer requirement. It really depends on your application. But these question can deliver insightful answers for beginners, and even more experienced developers. The keyword here is **[scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing))**.

The typical setup I prefer, bare metal real-time:

- Main runs all low priority and idle tasks. Main bases these timings on the systick timer that ticks every 1 ms: `if( (now - then) > delay ){ then = now; foo(); }`
  These tasks can be interrupted by everything, except in a critical zone (when using ISR threadspace data). 
  Low priority tasks are blinking LED's and handling communications.
- There are peripheral interrupts and timers that set IRQ pending bits to signal real-time work is ready to be done. Eg: read uart or adc register before overrun.
- The interrupt priorities and timers are setup in a way that the work is done in the correct order at the correct time. Eg: when processing ADC samples, and the hardware alarm IRQ arrives, this is handled immediately.

This way I have the DMA signal samples are ready to be processed, whilst a synchronized timer at a lower frequency set the IRQ-pending for the process loop. The process loop must run after the samples, thus has lower priority in the NVIC.

**Advantage:** Real time performance is not impeded when the communication channel is overflowed with data.
**Disadvantage:** The cpu never sleeps long.
The ISR's of the real time tasks may not exceed their time window. This is where Windowed Watchdog Timers are useful. Also, idle tasks will only run when there is time to spare. They might be late.

A similar option here is to use a real time operating system. Like ChibiOS.

However, when you're a battery application you don't want the MCU to wake up every second. You want the MCU to wake up only when work has to be done. You can do this in two ways.

1. Multiple hardware timers signal the wake-up event.
   This requires multiple timers to keep running and might still use too much energy.
2. Tickless operation. You use **one timer**, the chip wakes up and does work when the time is reached. Then it reloads the timer compare with the time of the next deadline. If your intervals are long enough apart you can use the RTC for this to get ultra low power consumption.

**Advantage:** chip is allowed to go to sleep for longer period depending on workload.
**Disadvantage:** the design is a bit more complicated to implement and debug.

Similar option here is to use a tickless operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not using a real time OS, I'd use a timer to do the time critical stuff (if it's handled with few clock cycles) and long timer counters through an interrupt and use non time critical stuff and longer periods in the main loop (with or without a watchdog timer/sleep).

The interrupts will interrupt the main loop stuff so you can be sure the time critical stuff happens when it needs to, the less time critical stuff happens whenever it can.

You could use a state machine in the main loop to do the logic stuff to make sure everything is done in the right order, things are checked, loaded, sensors read etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right answer here, best practices would be to implement the design to meet the requirements, since requirements for a project vary from project to project there is no single right answer.  One common solution will fail to work right for a wide array of products, as would another common solution.  You could force one solution but that can add a lot of hacked up band-aids simply adding risk to the project, possibly lead to failure and or recalls or field upgrades that were unecessary that make the product and the company look bad. Do your system engineering and most of the time the correct solution will simply present itself, dont do your system engineering and the failures will simply present themselves.